# How to turn my Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty (unity) to look like GNOME Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, ubuntu-unity

I am a **beginner** to Linux environment. 
I have installed **Ubuntu 14.04 (unity)** alongside windows.
I would like to make my Ubuntu look like **GNOME** version of Ubuntu.
What should i do to turn it look like that?
Is it possible to turn it **without removing** the whole OS?

Please suggest me a way.

Answer (score 0):

Type the following on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
And when PC asks which display to use, select "gdm".
```

For the Ubuntu GNOME Applications:, type the following on the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-weather gnome-music gnome-maps cheese gnome-documents
```

This gives you the full Ubuntu GNOME Experience without installing a fresh OS.

Comment: Can i change it back to my original view (trusty view)?

Comment: You could do `apt-get remove "package name"`.

Comment: "package name" insists gdm right?

Comment: "package name" includes `gdm` `gnome-shell`, `ubutu-gnome-desktop`

Comment: But if there's a problem, you could do:
`apt-get install ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-settings`

Comment: aravind@Aravind:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnome-shel

Comment: It's `shell` not `shel`

Comment: The change did not completely turn my unity to gnome. Only the login screen and the grub menu background color changed. And also the change slowed my computer very much. Any minimizing action of window results in hang of my computer.There were many bugs hope so. Is there a way to bring the original look of GNOME with all those themes and gadgets and graphics?
Now i removed those package completely.
what should i do?